# Not Getting Which Parameter will Pass to the Function

Tags: java

In function `addFriend(Person friend)`, I'm not getting which parameter will pass to this function. If I pass a String parameter it encountered a error incompatible type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person
{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Person> friends;

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        friends = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given friend to this Person's friends list.
     * @param friend the friend to add.
     */
    public void addFriend(Person friend)
    {
        friends.add(friend);
    }



 }
```

Comment: You need to pass it a `Person`.

Comment: Read this line again addFriend(Person friend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a Person instance :

```
Person a = new Person("John");
Person b = new Person("Mike");
a.addFriend(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using this class somewhat like

```
Person john = new Person("John");
Person jane = new Person("Jane");

// John adds Jane as a friend   
john.addFriend(jane);
```

Here basically the class can work with instances of its own type.

Take for example, you can have a `List` of `List` objects.

```
List<List> list1 = new ArrayList<List>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add(list2); // Here List.add() takes a List itself
```